# What should be the signing key for the AWS HTTP Post example?

Tags: c#, http-post, aws-sdk

I am trying to walk through the sample code using the values in the "Example: Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST (Using AWS Signature Version 4)" page, but could not get the same signature value posted on the page.

The page does not show the value for the signing key.  Does anybody know what it supposed to be?  Thanks.

```
namespace TestAWSSignature
{
    class Program
    {
    // Values from aws example page.
    const string aKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
    const string anID = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
    const string aRegion = "us-east-1";
    const string aService = "s3";
    const string aBucket = "sigv4examplebucket";
    const string HMACSHA256 = "HMACSHA256";
    const string aDate = "20151229";

    const string SCHEME = "AWS4";
    const string ALGORITHM = "HMAC-SHA256";
    const string TERMINATOR = "aws4_request";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initial to value from aws example page.
        string base64PolicyString = "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";
        byte[] policyStringBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64PolicyString);

        // compute the signing key
        KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(HMACSHA256);
        kha.Key = DeriveSigningKey(HMACSHA256, aKey, aRegion, aDate, aService);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Signing Key: {0}.\n", System.Convert.ToBase64String(kha.Key)));
        // SigningKey value is: y87x6+rvyCzOZTC58KmuWYhGBl9cW64GdL1evEulLSg=
        // Is this the correct value?

        // Compute the signature.
        byte[] signature = kha.ComputeHash(policyStringBytes);
        string signatureString = ToHexString(signature, true);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Signature: {0}.\n", signatureString));
        // The computed signature value is:
        // 00e98ae3199cdbfeba701f9efa66510f23f0295ab6d6f4d14202f8ef2d11956c
        // But according to the aws example page it should be:
        // 8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }

    // Functions below are straight from AWSSignatureV4-S3-Sample code.
    /// Compute and return the multi-stage signing key for the request.
    static byte[] DeriveSigningKey(string algorithm, string awsSecretAccessKey, string region, string date, string service)
    {
        const string ksecretPrefix = SCHEME;
        char[] ksecret = null;

        ksecret = (ksecretPrefix + awsSecretAccessKey).ToCharArray();

        byte[] hashDate = ComputeKeyedHash(algorithm, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ksecret), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(date));
        byte[] hashRegion = ComputeKeyedHash(algorithm, hashDate, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(region));
        byte[] hashService = ComputeKeyedHash(algorithm, hashRegion, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(service));
        return ComputeKeyedHash(algorithm, hashService, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TERMINATOR));
    }


    /// Compute and return the hash of a data blob using the specified algorithm and key

    static byte[] ComputeKeyedHash(string algorithm, byte[] key, byte[] data)
    {
        var kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
        kha.Key = key;
        return kha.ComputeHash(data);
    }

    /// Helper to format a byte array into string
    static string ToHexString(byte[] data, bool lowercase)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(data[i].ToString(lowercase ? "x2" : "X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you may want to put a link to the page mentioned...

Comment: Currently the link is:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html
And link for the C# source is:
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/samples/AmazonS3SigV4_Samples_CSharp.zip

Comment: Amazon provides this page to calculate the signing key:  https://ritish.s3.amazonaws.com/sigv4Process.html.  So our signing key is correct, but the signature is not.  The search for the problem continues ...